# Code standard (not style) enforcer for Eclipse

Tags: java, c++, coding-style, eclipse-plugin

Is there some coding standard enforcer for use with Eclipse (a plugin or something)? I know I can use "Window > Preferences > [Language] > Code Style" to suggest conventions, but these are not enforced.

In other words, I want Coding standard violations to be marked as "Errors" and Coding style violations as "Warnings".

Thanks and regards,
Karthick S.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You got several options to do that :

- PMD http://pmd.sourceforge.net/eclipse/
- Eclipse Checkstyle http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/
- Findbugs http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/
- You  can also integrate these plugins with your CI Server, for example Sonar For Hudson. Note that since 2011, Hudson has changed it's name to Jenkins. http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Sonar+plugin

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse [checkstyle plugin](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) should do this :)

Answer (score 3):

have a look at http://pmd.sourceforge.net/